# Issues with ave function in R: error "cannot allocate vector of size 419 kb."

Tags: r, memory-management, aggregate, plyr

For data in long format, I am trying to generate a sequence of 1:length of event to count length (time) of each event within ID, to look like this:

```
ID   Event  Time
1    1      1
1    1      2
1    1      3 
1    2      1
1    2      2
1    2      3
```

This seems simple enough using ave:

```
time <- ave(event, ID, FUN = sequence)
```

The code works fine in a data set of 1000 rows. However, on the full data set of 134000 rows and file size of 3mb, my computer practically freezes for ~ 40 minutes and I get the error "cannot allocate vector of size 419kb."  I am running the 64 bit version of R, and my machine has 4 gb of RAM. The file size does not seem especially large and the task not too burdensome, so I thought it was an issue with ave and I tried the same thing using aggregate, then ddply from the plyr package, and had the same issue. I also tried on a laptop with 8 gb of RAM, increasing the memory limit in R, and clearing all other applications to free up memory. Is this a memory-intensive task I'm trying to compete? And is there a more efficient alternative?

Comment: It wouldn't work because `sequence` is getting the sequence of each value and `ave` returns a vector of same length as the original 'event'.  What you may need is `seq` i.e. `with(df1, ave(Event, ID, FUN = seq))` or instead of `seq`, it could be also `seq_along`.  A faster option would be `library(data.table); setDT(df1)[, Seq := seq_len(.N), ID]`

Comment: Thank you. I just tried this and it produced the length of the ID, not event, which is what I'm trying to do. I should have been more explicit. The code I provided did work as intended but only on a much smaller data set.

Comment: In that case, you may also need 'Even't as grouping variable i.e. `with(df1, ave(Event, Event, ID, FUN = seq))#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3`

Comment: I put event as the grouping variable and that seems to have done it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sequence` as `FUN` may not work as expected.  For e.g.

```
sequence(c(6, 5))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5

seq_along(c(6, 5))
#[1] 1 2
```

Note that in the former case, it is returning a vector of length 11.

---

`ave` expects the output `vector` to be of the same `length` as the initial `vector`

So, based on this, it would be better to use `seq_along` as the `FUN` argument in `ave`

```
df1$Time <- with(df1, ave(Event, Event, ID, FUN = seq_along))
```

---

A faster option would be using `data.table`, where we assign (`:=`) the sequence after grouping by 'ID' and 'Event'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Time := seq_len(.N), .(ID, Event)]
```